# Need help understanding how to calculate tpd while static hazards are involved

Tags: logic-gates, logic-hazard

I need help understanding how to calculate tpd while static hazards are involved,

Given this circuit: (the output F is constant 0)
[image]
[image]
I found out that if X and Y are initated to 0 and we change Y to 1 we get an hazard after the AND gates (0->1->0) which I know cause a delay in the circuit even though the output is constant.

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate the delay, for example what delay should I take into consideration (HL,LH) for the AND gates.

If I could get an explaintion and an example calculating the delay from Y to F it would help a lot (not graphic if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 paths for X and 3 paths for Y to F. You can see it both in schematic and functional equation.

\$F= (X!+Y!)\cdot ((X+Y!)\cdot Y)~~~\$    or
\$F=(X!+Y!)\cdot (X\cdot Y+Y\cdot Y!))\$

If input = LH we use the inverted delay tHL for the inverter output and same polarity for OR,AND.

Thus the metastable transition times may be added up as follows. 
[image]

We see the stable F=0 but transitions for X,X! and Y,Y! may be added up to determine the worst case glitch with F=1.

> A better version of this could be an edge detector and often done with edge-type logic phase-detectors used in PLL's.  **Can you compute the Y glitch?**  What about X?

FYI... The transitions are based on a fixed load capacitance like 15 pF for tLH or tHL due to the min/max R=RdsOn  results in dV/dt=Vdd/T(~RC) due to PFETs used for tLH and NFETs used for tHL in addition with internal delays.